# WCF client, lots of ports

Tags: c#, wcf

I had occasion to use TCPView to look at network connections while I was developing a .NET thick client that connects to a WCF service and noticed that for every request, a new port is opened and then sticks around in the TIME_WAIT state for a while.

Yes, I've used WCF for a while now, but I didn't know this. I read that it's normal (part of the way TCP works) but it seems kind of bizarre to me.

I'm worried that a user could fill up all the available ports if they keep clicking around the application really fast (causing lots of service requests, sometimes multiple calls per click). Is that ever a practical problem, or should I just not worry about it?